# which mail server can save the status of a sent letter in the database

Tags: postgresql, database-connection, postfix-mta

Help, please: which mail server can save the status of a sent letter in the database? Now I parse the SandMal log, then call the procedure in Postgres and save the status of the letter. The problem is that with a large shipment, the status will be in the database only after a day. Or tell me what I can google on this issue.

In this case, it is necessary that the mail server operates in mail transfer agent mode (MTA).

Thank you very much in advance!

I read about Postfix, it has a database client. But I still don’t understand whether it’s possible to use Postgres procedures.

Comment: Consider using PL/Perl or PL/Python.